# Route [/admin] not defined. не видит маршрут на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день делаю редирект но выдает ошибку Route [/admin] not defined

```
 if($formFields['email']==$data['email'] && $formFields['password']==$data['password']){
        return redirect()->intended(route('/admin'));
     }
Route::get('/admin',[\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: вообще-то для админских роутов есть отдельный файл `admin.php`, а сам роут пишется как `Route::get('/',[\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.index');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `route` необходимо указывать имя маршрута. Для этого необходимо это имя задать:

```
// routes/web
Route::get('/admin',[\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('admin');

// Контроллер
return redirect()->route('admin');
```

Comment: понял, спасибо)